# Azure Search, Is there a way to add Query when importing from SQL

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

When Importing data to an Index in Azure Search, from SQL (progrematically not through the interface), Is there a way to add Query to filter the data come from the SQL table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the REST API documentation for [`Create Data Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn946876.aspx), as of today it is not possible to define a query to filter the data that populates an index.

However I read somewhere that you can create a `View` and use that as the data source for populating the index. However when using a view, you will not be able to use SQL Integrated change tracking for change / deletion detection. However, you will still be able to use High Water Mark change detection and Soft Delete Column deletion detection.

Also, please vote for [this UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/9893490-support-user-provided-query-in-sql-indexer) to request adding support for `query` parameter.